# How do I format webpageURL to get WatchKit to handoff user to a website in Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, handoff

I have an app that generates a small amount of information in a WatchKit app. I then want to hand the user off to Safari on another device to pursue more information at a website, with specific information in a url query string. I've written this:

```
var QueryVar = SomeArray.description
var website = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/index.html?query="+QueryVar)

updateUserActivity("com.example.myapp.anactivity", userInfo: nil, webpageURL: website)
```

When I `println(website)` it comes up `nil`, and the console warns that both `userInfo` and `webpageURL` cannot be `nil`. I've tried a number of different ways of formatting that URL as a string, nothing seems to work.

The Swift documentation is good but lacks examples. 
Most of the examples out there don't bother with the `webpageURL` element.

What's worse is even if I get this to not generate an error message, I won't be sure that it works because `webpageURL` isn't supported in the IOS simulator. Does anyone have some working code, ideally tested on an actual watch, they can share?

Comment: Mm, yeah sorry, included that for completeness and didn't include my declaration. Added it now, though I've removed it for testing and I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: println QueryVar. You'll see why it won't work. What are you trying to access from the array?

Comment: Boom. I'm an idiot. Indeed, while the array was stringified, it wasn't restricted to elements, it was literally [7,5,7,6,7] brackets, commas, and all. Thanks, Schemetrical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Schemetrical who pointed out my error in thinking that

```
  QueryVar.description
```

would yield only the elements of an array stringified. As that variable contained brackets and commas it was illegal content for an NSURL type. I cleaned up the code and got to a working solution:

```
 var URLwithQuery = "http://www.example.com?query="+QueryVar

   var urlPath: String = URLwithQuery
   var website: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

  updateUserActivity("com.example.myapp.anactivity", userInfo: nil, webpageURL: website)
```